# how to combine lists to get a vector?

Tags: r, list, vector

for the package termstrc I need

ISIN: chr [1:115] "AT0000383690" "AT0000383690" ...

that means if a bond "xxx" has for example 5 Cashflows and an other bond "yyy" has 3 Cashflows then the vector need to look like this:

("xxx" "xxx" "xxx" "xxx" "xxx" "yyy" "yyy" "yyy")

So now I received with

*for(i in 1:length(count)) {part[[i]] <-rep(ISIN[i],count[i]);}*

where **"part**" is a list and 
**"count**" is a vector which shows how many times do I need a bond

**So I had now:**
part[1] = ("xxx" "xxx" "xxx" "xxx" "xxx") and 
part[2] = ("yyy" "yyy" "yyy")

**I need** ("xxx" "xxx" "xxx" "xxx" "xxx" "yyy" "yyy" "yyy")

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: do.call(c, part[1])
Error in do.call(c, part[1]) : 
  'what' must be a function or character string...... doesnt work

Comment: do.call(c, part)
Error in do.call(c, part) : 'what' must be a function or character string

Comment: str(part)
List of 80
 $ : chr [1:30] "026351AZ9" "026351AZ9" "026351AZ9" "026351AZ9" ...
 $ : chr [1:9] "026351BC9" "026351BC9" "026351BC9" "026351BC9" ...

Comment: dput(part)
list(c("026351AZ9", "026351AZ9", "026351AZ9", "026351AZ9", "026351AZ9", 
"026351AZ9", "026351AZ9", "026351AZ9", "026351AZ9", "026351AZ9", 
"026351AZ9", "026351AZ9", "026351AZ9", "026351AZ9", "026351AZ9", 
"026351AZ9", "026351AZ9", "026351AZ9", "026351AZ9", "026351AZ9", 
"026351AZ9", "026351AZ9", "026351AZ9", "026351AZ9", "026351AZ9", 
"026351AZ9", "026351AZ9", "026351AZ9", "026351AZ9", "026351AZ9"
), c("026351BC9", "026351BC9", "026351BC9", "026351BC9", "026351BC9", 
"026351BC9", "026351BC9", "026351BC9", "026351BC9"), c("031905AA0",

Comment: I have the answer. thank you very much for your help. But I can also put it in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rep()` is vectorized, so you can just do

```
part <- rep(ISIN, count)
```

Comment: I did this already. So I receive a Lists with vectors with part[1] =("xxx" "xxx" "xxx" "xxx" "xxx")  and part[2] =("yyy" "yyy" "yyy"). I want to get them in one vector.

Comment: No, I mean run that line of code exactly as it is, without the `for` loop.  It will give you a single vector, with each value repeated the appropriate number of times.